# spyder project navigator does not show functions within

Tags: python, spyder

I start programming in Spyder, but it does not show the functions within scripts in the project navigator panel (like Eclipse does).

Here a plot to illustrate the difference.

[image]

Could someone help me to setup Spyder to show functions into each .py scripts?

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Our Projects pane doesn't display functions or classes declared inside files.

To view that information, you need to open a different pane called `Outline`. You can do that by going to the menu

`View > Panes > Outline`

Comment: Cordova. Ok, it shows functions from the current script, but the panel is not elegant at all. Thank you.